# Getting an audio file size in kb

Tags: iphone, objective-c, audio, avaudioplayer, nsdata

In my application I have an audio files stored in caf and aac format. I need to get the size of the audio file in kb,from the audio url. Is there any way to achieve this requirement?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `NSFileManager` to request the attributes dictionary, then get the size from the attributes dictionary:

```
NSFileManager * fileManager = [NSFileManager new];
NSError * error = 0;
NSDictionary * attr = [fileManager attributesOfItemAtPath:path error:&error];
// error checking
unsigned long long size = [attr fileSize];
[fileManager release];
```

this is available on iOS 2 and OSX.5

Comment: Hi it works fine ,Thank you. But I already did that in another way I mentioned below.

Comment: @Siddharth Yes, creating an NSData representation and getting its length also works, but you should reserve that approach for when you need a `NSData` representation. If you *need* a `NSData` representation, then your approach works fine. If you don't need a `NSData` representation, then one should favor my approach because it will save a lot of CPU, disk activity, and memory compared to creating an `NSData` instance from the file.

Answer (score 1):

you could use following command-line

$ curl --head $URL_OF_AUDIO_FILE | grep Content-Length | awk '{print ($2/1024);}'

[[ Example for a PDF ]]

curl --head http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.pdf | grep Content-Length | awk '{print ($2/1024);}'

Answer (score 1):

You can use CF/NSURL's property accessors, which are available on iOS 5 and up, and OSX.6 and up:

```
id value = 0;
// Key for the file’s size in bytes, returned as an NSNumber object:
NSString * key = NSURLFileSizeKey;
NSError * error = 0;
BOOL result = [audioFileURL getResourceValue:&value forKey:key error:&error];
... error checking here ...
NSNumber * number = value;
```

There are multiple keys for file size information, another may be better suited for your needs.

Comment: I tried this, but I am getting the number as null. I got the result bool as YES.Any reason ? Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: is the file readable? also, in ios4, the method does nothing.

Comment: ok - on iOS, you can use this method on 5.0 and greater. i have updated my answer with that detail.

Comment: @Siddharth i provided a new answer which has better backwards compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by converting it to NSData and getting its length property.

```
    NSError *err = nil;
    NSData *audioData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:file options:0 error:&err];
    NSString *audioLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%dkB",[audioData length]/1000];
    NSLog(@"[audioData bytes]==%@",audioLength);
```